# Django Rest Framework passing context to Meta

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

is there a way to pass serializer context to class Meta? In general, I want to include a URL to nested API views only in Browsable API, so I pass a 'renderer' value to serializer context, and want to check it in Meta to include additional fields or not to do so. Maybe there is a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override your serializer `__init__` and switch out the hyperlinked field in `self.fields` for whatever you please ([documentation example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields) for dynamically changing fields) based on the [accepted renderer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#accepted_renderer) on `self.context['request']`.

Comment: The proposed solution worked perfectly, thank you) Documentation example, though, proposes to `kwargs.pop('fields', None)`, despite that no such kwarg is being passed. `self.fields.pop('field_name', None)` worked fine